# Reset tap counter

Tags: ios, core-data

I am creating a simple knit project (Core Data) app which can be used to count patterns for knit projects.

On my initial view I do have a `UILabel` (to display the counts), `UIButton`s for + and - and Reset.

Everything gets controlled over three methods (plus, minus, reset). Following is the code of the plus method:

```
- (IBAction)plus:(id)sender
{        
    if ([sender tag] == 0)
    {
        counterA=counterA +1;
        _IncRowcount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counterA];
    }
```

Everything works fine, the complete knit project including the current state of the count gets saved and also the fetch works fine.

But when I want to create a new empty project, `UILabel` is empty, but when I press the + `UIButton`, the counter starts from the last saved count.

I have tried almost everything but I can't solve this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think we have nearly enough information to help you. It sounds like you're saving the count somewhere, maybe even in more than one place, and that's why it's being restored. Also sounds like the kind of problem that arises from misuse of a singleton. But without more info it's really just guessing.

Comment: How do you declare `counterA`? It might be that you declared it as a static variable then it would preserve the old value.

Comment: counterA is declared as int counterA;...Then I do have a save method to save the content of _IncRowcount like this: self.Project.incrowcount = self.IncRowcount.text;

Comment: any idea, suggestions?